# Orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let $v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0)^{T},v_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1,0)^{T}, v_3=(t+1,t+1,t)^{T}$ three vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. For which values of $t$ is there an orthogonal application which maps canonical basis in $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$? I've been trying to solve and a necessary and sufficient condition is that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is an orthonormal basis (?).
Then what remains is a matter of calculations...

Answer (score 0):

We have that $v_1 \perp v_2$ and that $v_2 \perp v_3$.

Furthermore

$$v_1 \perp v_3 \iff 2t+2=0 \iff t=-1 \iff v_3=(0,0,-1).$$

Consequence: for $t=-1$ we have that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is an orthonormal basis.